# How do I prepare my javascript for minifying (using JSMin)?

Tags: javascript, minify, jslint

I need to check my javascript file for basic errors and poor practices before using JSMin to remove any chances of the script playing up once it have been compressed. Previously I used JSLint and this worked perfectly, but I have visited http://www.jslint.com/ again and it seems to pick up so many more errors than before (even on a script I know I have passed through JSLint before with no errors).

I'm aware of the options in JSLint but from memory I was just using the defaults the first time anyway:
`/*jslint maxerr: 50, indent: 4 */`

Is there a better way to test my script, or am I not using JSLint the same way I may have originally?
JSLint even picks up on the undefined `$` which I use for jQuery, when I know this wasn't the case previously.

Answer (score 1):

JSLint is probably still what you want. You can get it to calm down about the $ by adding an extern statement, here's an example:

```
/*jslint bitwise: true, browser: true, eqeqeq: true, evil: true, 
onevar: true, undef: true, white: true */
/*extern Ext, $ */
```

You can check out the options on this page: http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#options